# Debugging Android init language

Tags: android, operating-system, init

I am trying to modify a file related to init.rc in Android 9 (using a rooted snapdragon 845 development platform from Lantronix). The file that I want to modify is "/vendor/etc/init/hostapd.android.rc".

The purpose is to add a default route (gateway) once the WIFI hotspot is enabled. The code works greatly in a terminal:

```
ip address add 192.168.43.1/24 dev wlan0
```

Therefore, I followed the init readme.md from ASOP which is available here (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md). And I have modified the hostapd.android.rc adding the following lines:

```
on property:init.svc.hostapd=running
exec - -- /system/bin/sleep 2
exec - -- /system/bin/ip address add 192.168.43.1/24 dev wlan0
```

The code above is supposed to be triggered once the hotspot is enabled, wait two seconds and add the gateway address to wlan0 (my hotspot network).

It is the content of the hostapd.android.rc file:

```
#
# init.rc fragment for hostapd on Android
# Copyright (c) 2002-2016, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi>
#
# This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
# See README for more details.
#

on post-fs-data
    mkdir /data/vendor/wifi 0770 wifi wifi
    mkdir /data/vendor/wifi/hostapd 0770 wifi wifi
    mkdir /data/vendor/wifi/hostapd/sockets 0770 wifi wifi

service hostapd /vendor/bin/hw/hostapd
    interface android.hardware.wifi.hostapd@1.0::IHostapd default
    class main
    capabilities NET_ADMIN NET_RAW
    user wifi
    group wifi net_raw net_admin
    disabled
    oneshot

on property:init.svc.hostapd=running
    exec - -- /system/bin/sleep 2
    exec - -- /system/bin/ip address add 192.168.43.1/24 dev wlan0
```

However, it doesn't work and I don't know the reason. I wonder how I can check if there is any error. Nothing is displayed neither using `logcat` or `dumpsys`.

How can I debug the execution of hostapd.android.rc file? I would like to verify the following things:

- Is the property "init.svc.hostapd=running" triggered?
- What is the output of the executed commands? Can I add 'echo' for debugging?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can write to `/dev/kmesg` (read with `adb shell dmesg` command) in init scripts, here is an example:

```
write /dev/kmsg "product model is ${ro.product.model}"
```

Run `adb shell dmesg -w` to watch the init logs including messages you added.

You can also increase the verbosity of Android init by adding this to `system/core/rootdir/init.rc`:

```
on early-init
    loglevel 7
    write /proc/sys/kernel/printk_ratelimit_burst 500
```

Level 7 is the most verbose level supported by init in Android. The printk burst ratelimit likely needs to be increased as well or the kernel will probably drop log messages and print the following:

```
init: 58 output lines suppressed due to ratelimiting
```